# What did I just do to my rig? Audio went crazy and had to reboot

Tags: equipment-operation, icom, icom-ic-7300

[Video](https://streamable.com/zlun4)

I was experimenting with different settings on my IC-7300 and trying out manually controlling the RF Gain with AGC off.  Too much gain for a moment caused audio clipping followed by the audio going into a weird state.  Even after flipping AGC back on it was still acting bizarre (you can see in the video).

At this point I'm in a cold sweat-- did I just brick my new radio like an idiot?  I turned the radio off, said a quick prayer, and turned it back on.  Thank god the audio is back.

Currently kicking myself right now.  I can't just leave well enough alone.  I always have to tinker.

Could I have broken something in the ADC or elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's highly doubtful you could break anything by turning those knobs. At worst, you just end up with horrible clipping and distortion as you experienced.

The IC-7300 is a direct-sampling SDR. It's possible you found some software bug. Or it could just be that the AGC wasn't on long enough to adjust the gain back down. Complicating matters is that tuned to exactly 10 MHz, the carrier of that AM station is at or very near DC, which might put the signal closer to the clipping threshold, without being audible.

In any case, I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I was hoping it was just some kind of software issue with it handling an unusual scenario. Glad you think the same thing.